# CSS3 Icon: inserted content isn't placed consistently

Tags: html, css, insert, icons

I'm creating icons using only CSS3. So far so good, but I've run into a problem with the simplest one.
I just want to have an "!" centered in a circle, but its position isn't consistent. Sometimes it's a pixel higher, a pixel to the left, or both.
I have no idea what's causing this.

[Here's a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gfobyh3e/)

```
.nos {
    position: relative;
    height: 12px; width: 12px;
    border: 2px solid #e04006;
    border-radius: 50%; -webkit-border-radius: 50%; -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    color: #e04006;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: default;
}

.nos:hover {
    overflow: visible;
}

.nos span {
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 18px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px; line-height: 16px; text-decoration: underline;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.nos:before {
    content: '\21';
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 16px; width: 16px;
    display: block;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace; text-align: center; font-size: 12px; line-height: 12px; font-weight: bold; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I managed to fix it after some tinkering. Not sure what did the trick.

```
.nos {
    position: relative;
    width: 12px; height: 12px;
    border: 2px solid #e04006;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%; -moz-border-radius: 50%; border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #e04006;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: default;
}

.nos:hover {
    overflow: visible;
}

.nos span {
    position: absolute; top: -2px; left: -2px;
    height: 16px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: underline; font-size: 14px; line-height: 16px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.nos:before {
    content: '\21';
    position: absolute; top: -2px; left: -2px;
    width: 16px;
    display: block;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;  font-size: 13px; line-height: 13px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gfobyh3e/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `height: 16px; width: 16px;` from `.nos:before`

[**Update Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gfobyh3e/2/)

Comment: Exclamation placement still looks inconsistent on my end.

Comment: Thanks though. Looks like I fixed it, I'll post an answer.